# How can I append react-native components to view without re-rendering?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Initially `componentWillMount()` will run a `fetch()` to an `API` endpoint & then save the `javascript object` to the redux store.

Now my problem is that when it comes to rendering the next set of components it re-renders all of them (meaning there's a little flash on the screen because of the rendering).

So essentially `onScroll` past a certain point it will run the same `fetch()` api call & grab a new list of javascript objects. It then grabs the data from the redux store & loops through it appending each new postComponent to the layout state.

```
handleScroll (event: Object) {
    const offset = event.nativeEvent.contentOffset.y;
    const screenHeight = Dimensions.get('window').height;
    // Just for dev purposes until I find a proper way of determining half way down screen
    if(offset >= screenHeight/2){
      console.log("Halfway past...");
      this.props.FeedActions.fetchFeed(this.props.feed.nextUrl, true);
    }

  }


 render() {
    var feed = this.props.feed;

    if (!_.has(feed, 'posts')) {
      return <ActivityIndicatorIOS />;
    }

    // Append more posts to state
    for (var i = 0; i < _.size(feed.posts); i++) {
      this.state.postComponents.push(
            <PostComponent post={ feed.posts[i] } key={ "post_"+feed.posts[i].postId+Math.random() }/>
      );
    }

    return (  
      <ScrollView key={Math.random()} onScroll={this.handleScroll.bind(this)}>
        { this.state.postComponents }
      </ScrollView>
    )
  }
};
```

Is there a way around this? I thought react wouldn't re-render components that are already render, only the ones that are changed? But I guess in this case my components are all dynamic so that means they will be re-rendered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in how you're creating your keys. What you want is a key that uniquely identifies that particular node, consistently, and doesn't change every render. Since you use `Math.random()` as part of your key, it changes the key every render, so react rebuilds that node. Try using postId without the random number trailing it.